# Scala "overloaded method apply with alternatives" - understand method signatures

Tags: scala, plotly, data-class

I use external library plotly-scala, a graphing package that implements a `Layout` [object](https://github.com/alexarchambault/plotly-scala/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/plotly/layout/Layout.scala).

I need to use the `shape` parameter, which seems to require a verbose method signature and I would like to understand why and if there's any workaround.

Shape objects are defined [here](https://github.com/alexarchambault/plotly-scala/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/plotly/layout/Shape.scala). It may or may not help to know that that scala-plotly classes rely on a [3rd party library](https://index.scala-lang.org/alexarchambault/data-class/data-class/0.1.1?target=_2.13) by the same author.

I define working and non working examples:

```scala
// Related question: why do I have to use Some(...) everywhere?
// I'd prefer to write: new Shape(`type`="rect",xref="x", etc.)
val confidenceBand = new Shape(
    `type`=Some("rect"),
    xref=Some("x"),
    yref=Some("paper"),
    x0=Some("2.1"),
    y0=Some(0.0),
    x1=Some("3.2"),
    y1=Some(1.0),
    fillcolor=Some(Color.RGBA(156, 165, 196, 1.0)),
    opacity=Some(0.8),
    line=Some(Line(color = Color.RGBA(156, 165, 196, 1.0), width = 1.0)),
)

// No shape parameter -> non verbose signature, no need to use Some/None
val layout = Layout(
    title="Simulation",
    yaxis = Axis(
        title = "tbc")
)

// With shape parameter -> `overloaded method apply with alternatives:`
// See full error further down
val layout = Layout(
    title="Simulation",
    yaxis = Axis(
        title = "y"),
    shapes=Some(Seq(confidenceBand))
)

// With shape parameter and a verbose signature -> code compiles
val layout = Layout(
    title=Some("Simulation"),
    legend=None,
    width=None,
    height=None,
    showlegend=None,
    xaxis=None,
    yaxis = Some(Axis(
                    title = "y")),
    shapes=Some(Seq(confidenceBand)),
    xaxis1=None,
    xaxis2=None,
    xaxis3=None,
    xaxis4=None,
    yaxis1=None,
    yaxis2=None,
    yaxis3=None,
    yaxis4=None,
    barmode=None,
    autosize=None,
    margin=None,
    annotations=None,
    plot_bgcolor=None,
    paper_bgcolor=None,
    font=None,
    bargap=None,
    bargroupgap=None,
    hovermode=None,
    boxmode=None,
    scene=None,
    dragmode=None,
)
```

Can I get the second approach to work i.e. have the shape parameter but not having to litter the code with `None`'s?

Full error message:

```
cmd66.sc:1: overloaded method apply with alternatives:
  (title: Option[String],legend: Option[plotly.layout.Legend],width: Option[Int],height: Option[Int],showlegend: Option[scala.Boolean],xaxis: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],yaxis: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],xaxis1: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],xaxis2: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],xaxis3: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],xaxis4: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],yaxis1: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],yaxis2: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],yaxis3: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],yaxis4: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],barmode: Option[plotly.layout.BarMode],autosize: Option[scala.Boolean],margin: Option[plotly.layout.Margin],annotations: Option[Seq[plotly.layout.Annotation]],plot_bgcolor: Option[plotly.element.Color],paper_bgcolor: Option[plotly.element.Color],font: Option[plotly.layout.Font],bargap: Option[scala.Double],bargroupgap: Option[scala.Double],hovermode: Option[plotly.layout.HoverMode],boxmode: Option[plotly.layout.BoxMode],scene: Option[plotly.layout.Scene],dragmode: Option[String],shapes: Option[Seq[plotly.layout.Shape]])plotly.layout.Layout <and>
  (title: Option[String],legend: Option[plotly.layout.Legend],width: Option[Int],height: Option[Int],showlegend: Option[scala.Boolean],xaxis: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],yaxis: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],xaxis1: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],xaxis2: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],xaxis3: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],xaxis4: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],yaxis1: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],yaxis2: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],yaxis3: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],yaxis4: Option[plotly.layout.Axis],barmode: Option[plotly.layout.BarMode],autosize: Option[scala.Boolean],margin: Option[plotly.layout.Margin],annotations: Option[Seq[plotly.layout.Annotation]],plot_bgcolor: Option[plotly.element.Color],paper_bgcolor: Option[plotly.element.Color],font: Option[plotly.layout.Font],bargap: Option[scala.Double],bargroupgap: Option[scala.Double],hovermode: Option[plotly.layout.HoverMode],boxmode: Option[plotly.layout.BoxMode],scene: Option[plotly.layout.Scene])plotly.layout.Layout <and>
  ()plotly.layout.Layout <and>
  (title: String,legend: plotly.layout.Legend,width: Integer,height: Integer,showlegend: java.lang.Boolean,xaxis: plotly.layout.Axis,yaxis: plotly.layout.Axis,xaxis1: plotly.layout.Axis,xaxis2: plotly.layout.Axis,xaxis3: plotly.layout.Axis,xaxis4: plotly.layout.Axis,yaxis1: plotly.layout.Axis,yaxis2: plotly.layout.Axis,yaxis3: plotly.layout.Axis,yaxis4: plotly.layout.Axis,barmode: plotly.layout.BarMode,autosize: java.lang.Boolean,margin: plotly.layout.Margin,annotations: Seq[plotly.layout.Annotation],plot_bgcolor: plotly.element.Color,paper_bgcolor: plotly.element.Color,font: plotly.layout.Font,bargap: java.lang.Double,bargroupgap: java.lang.Double,hovermode: plotly.layout.HoverMode,boxmode: plotly.layout.BoxMode,scene: plotly.layout.Scene)plotly.layout.Layout
 cannot be applied to (title: String, yaxis: plotly.layout.Axis, shapes: Some[Seq[plotly.layout.Shape]])
val layout = Layout(
             ^
Compilation Failed
```

Comment: @deprecated("Use Layout() and chain-call .with* methods on it instead", "0.8.0")

Comment: _"Related question: why do I have to use Some(...) everywhere?"_ because the constructor expects `Options`, so you can not just pass the plain values, you need to wrap then into a `Option`, this is just **Scala** 101, it would be good to learn a little bit of the language before trying to use a third party library.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I get that if the method expects parameters of type `Option[A]` I need to return a Some[A] or a None, but why is that not the case with `Layout` (without shape parameter), whose signature in the source code also includes Option[A] types?

Comment: I mean, the answer may be because the library's author decided to allow two signatures, one with a restricted set of parameters but no Option[A] requirement, and another signature with all parameters but Option[A] types. That's what the error message suggests anyway, and I can live with it, but I'd like to make sure I am not missing a feature of the standard library that allows me to skip the option requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the "Layout() and chain-call .with*" hint, I just need to get head around what it means (maybe `Layout().with(title="simulation").with(shape=etc.)`?)

Comment: Is because `Layout` is defined differently than `Shape`, you can see that while the `Shape` class does accept `Options` the `apply` method in the companion does not, and rather uses `nulls`. - The hint means the class should be used like `Layout().withTitle("Simulation").withShape(...)`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ohhh.... I can see it clearly now. The `Layout`companion object's `apply` accepts "raw" values and creates the Option[A] for us. `Shape` has no similar companion object so we don't get this feature. Also, thanks for your explicit snippet, as using the chaining method does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clearly explained by @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez in the comments, the answer's in the companion object of `Layout`, which creates the Option[A] arguments from the A type parameter that we pass.

The apply method does not include the `shapes`parameter, hence the odd behaviour I described.

Furthermore, using the chaining method - suggested by the deprecated warning in the class constructor - gives me what I need:

```scala
val layout = Layout().
            withTitle("simulation").
            withYaxis(Axis(title = "y")).
            withShapes(Seq(confidenceBand))
```